# Debian Buster, Xen and Docker - Network bridge issue?

Tags: debian, docker, bridge, xen

I have a small home server running Debian. On this server I have a few VMs running and I recently installed Docker. I was actually planning to remove some of the VMs and use containers instead.
The setup seemed fine on Debian Stretch: I actually haven't had time to play with containers but both Xen and Docker were installed and Xen VMs were running fine.

Then I decided to upgrade to Debian Buster.
Since then, for some reasons, I cannot reach any of the VMs from the network, only from Dom0.
If I uninstall Docker, VMs are reachable again.

To me, it sounds like an issue with network bridges (docker0 and xenbr0) but networking is not my cup of tea. I have just no idea on how to fix that.

What do you think? Anyone knows what has changed with Buster that could explain this behavior?

Thank you very much.

Jean-François

Comment: Try this to see if that "fixes" the problem to narrow it down: `rmmod br_netfilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your iptables FORWARD chain. Docker is known (see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router)) to set this chain default policy to DROP.

Comment: Thank you @AlexD, you were right.
I added iptables rules on the DOCKER-USER chain so that traffic is now allowed. 
https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#add-iptables-policies-before-dockers-rules